# How does Pandas Series.interpolate in time work?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, interpolation, imputation

I have a time series index with few missing values here and there for temperature and humidity readings.

```
Time                   Temp1    Humidity1  
1/2/2017 13:00          31             48
1/2/2017 14:00          NaN             43
1/2/2017 15:00          25             39
```

Now, I want to know the algorithm behind series.interpolate(method = 'time') and series.interpolate(method = 'linear') because both of them gave me the same results. I couldn't find in the documentation anything regarding the internal algorithm of time interpolation.

Comment: See the documentation 
    ‘linear’: Ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced. This is the only method supported on MultiIndexes.

    ‘time’: Works on daily and higher resolution data to interpolate given length of interval.

In your case the equal spacing may be daily, so both may be giving same result. If you can provide more data, precise info can be provided.

  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html

Comment: I have edited the post